# how to open activity from adapter in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to open activity from adapter. It gives me error **Type Mismatch: inferred type is Intent but context was expected**. help me.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace the error line with

```
 context.startActivity(intent)
```